# PHP api call, but format is strange

Tags: php, json, api

[image: JSON Return (Image)]

What to do? since if i parse with json i only get the "xx.xx" values

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  $url = "https://www.henrikhjelm.se/api/getdata.php?lan=kronobergs-lan";
  $json = file_get_contents($url);
  $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
  
  foreach ($json_data as $value) {
    echo "Value: $value <br>";
  }

?>
```

this is the code I use, I only get the values that are in "" from the api. But I need both the first value and the value inside "". Don't know how to do it.

var_dump($json)

```
string(8728) "{"kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__biodiesel": "34.23","kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoStora_Vagen_6__biodiesel": "10.04","kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoArabygatan_53__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_MarkarydHassleholmsvagen_2__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoOstregardsgatan_51__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_MarkarydGlasbruksvagen_15_Stromsnasbruk__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_AlvestaBladingevagen_20__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_LjungbyHelsingborgsvagen__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_LjungbyNyponvagen_7__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_LesseboStorgatan_60__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_St1_VaxjoVingavagen_1__etanol": "19.14","kronobergslan_St1_VaxjoMorners_Vag_2__etanol": "19.14","kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSoderleden_2__etanol": "19.14","kronobergslan_Ingo_LjungbyHarabergsgatan__etanol": "19.14","kronobergslan_St1_LjungbyMarta_Ljungbergsvagen_56__etanol": "19.14","kronobergslan_St1_MarkarydDrottninggatan_50__etanol": "19.14","kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__etanol": "34.23","kronobergslan_Preem_TingsrydLokgatan__etanol": "19.41","kronobergslan_Preem_MarkarydUlvarydsvag__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoSodra_Vallviksvagen_352_51_Vaxjo__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_LjungbyRingvagen_1__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Preem_UppvidingeJarnvagsgatan_Aseda__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoVarnamovagen_Lammhult__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_UppvidingeVaxjovagen_Lenhovda__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoSandviksvagen__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoJonkopingsvagen_14_Lammhult__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoSambandsvagen_2__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Preem_LjungbyLanggatan_2__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_LjungbyLagan__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoNorremarksvagen_2__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoHejaregatan_17__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoEvedalsvagen__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_OKQ8_UppvidingeAspvagen_9_Alstermo__etanol": "19.39","kronobergslan_Preem_AlmhultS_Esplanaden__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_AlvestaFabriksgatan_3__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_AlmhultDanska_Vagen_4__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_Almhultalmhult_ringvagen_10__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_dinX_TingsrydSodra_vagen_19_urshult__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_AlmhultSodra_Ringvagen_10__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_VaxjoLjungadalsgatan_1__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Preem_LesseboStorgatan_56a__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoRadjursvagen__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoStora_Vagen_6__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_TingsrydStorgatan_113__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoHammerdalsvagen_3__etanol": "19.24","kronobergslan_Tanka_AlvestaBladingevagen_20__diesel": "24.57","kronobergslan_OKQ8_LjungbyHelsingborgsvagen__diesel": "24.57","kronobergslan_Tanka_LjungbyNyponvagen_7__diesel": "24.57","kronobergslan_OKQ8_LesseboStorgatan_60__diesel": "24.57","kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSoderleden_2__diesel": "24.53","kronobergslan_St1_VaxjoVingavagen_1__diesel": "24.47","kronobergslan_St1_VaxjoMorners_Vag_2__diesel": "24.47","kronobergslan_Ingo_LjungbyHarabergsgatan__diesel": "24.47","kronobergslan_St1_LjungbyMarta_Ljungbergsvagen_56__diesel": "24.47","kronobergslan_St1_MarkarydDrottninggatan_50__diesel": "24.47","kronobergslan_dinX_TingsrydSodra_vagen_19_urshult__diesel": "24.46","kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoStora_Vagen_6__diesel": "24.45","kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoOstregardsgatan_51__diesel": "24.13","kronobergslan_Smart_Energy_LesseboSkruv_Lagervagen_1__diesel": "23.83","kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__diesel": "100.00","kronobergslan_Tanka_VaxjoLjungadalsgatan_1__diesel": "52.39","kronobergslan_Circle_K_VaxjoSodra_Vallviksvagen_352_51_Vaxjo__diesel": "29.12",
```

var_dump($json_data)

```
array(141) { ["kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__biodiesel"]=> string(5) "34.23" ["kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoStora_Vagen_6__biodiesel"]=> string(5) "10.04" ["kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoArabygatan_53__etanol"]=> string(5) "19.24" ["kronobergslan_Tanka_MarkarydHassleholmsvagen_2__etanol"]=> string(5) "19.24" ["kronobergslan_Preem_VaxjoOstregardsgatan_51__etanol"]=> string(5) "19.24" ["kronobergslan_OKQ8_MarkarydGlasbruksvagen_15_Stromsnasbruk__etanol"]=> string(5) "19.24" ["kronobergslan_Tanka_AlvestaBladingevagen_20__etanol"]=> string(5) "19.24" ["kronobergslan_OKQ8_LjungbyHelsingborgsvagen__etanol"]=> string(5) "19.24"
```

I'm trying to build a table with name "kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__biodiesel" and value "34.23"

Comment: Please share code not an image so we can help you better and be more specific about your question

Comment: gguney, shared the code too

Comment: This question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to do and where are you stuck? What do you mean by _"strange"_ and _"i only get the "xx.xx" values"_? Can you please show a proper example of what `$json` contains (use `var_dump()`), what `$json_data` contains (another `var_dum()`) and what you're trying to get from it? Post that as text, not images.

Comment: added the dump request, I'm trying to build a table with both values beside of eachother.

Comment: Are you saying that you need the _keys_ as well? Then you need to change your your foreach to: `foreach ($json_data as $key => $value)`. Now you have the key in `$key` and the value in `$value`. Read more [in the manual about foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). And there's nothing strange about the json format.

Comment: Yeah, I need the key names since it includes the position of the petrol station. I'm trying to build a petrol station list with the prices, so I would need the key name and the key value.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I'm new to the whole thing. I will try to do more digging next time. Thanks M. Eriksson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow community.
First of all, you are looping through values only. You need to slightly modify your `foreach` loop to include keys. Here is how you do it:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.henrikhjelm.se/api/getdata.php?lan=kronobergs-lan";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$entries = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($entries as $key => $value) {
    echo("key: $key<br>");
    echo("value: $value<br>");
    echo("<br>");
}
```

The output is the following:

```
key: kronobergslan_Ingo_VaxjoSmedjegatan_28__Morners_vag__biodiesel
value: 34.23

key: kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoStora_Vagen_6__biodiesel
value: 10.04

key: kronobergslan_OKQ8_VaxjoArabygatan_53__etanol
value: 19.24
```

I hope this is the desired result. Let me know if you have any questions left.